# При перезаливке рабочего проекта получил Fatal (php7.3.3/Symfony4.2)

Tags: php, symfony

Решил добавить гит в собственные проект. Соответственно создал репу на гитхабе, склонировал эту пустую репу, в нее залил рабочий проект. После всех этих телодвижений получил fatal по памяти:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /home/site/my_site/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 107
>
> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /home/site/my_site/vendor/symfony/debug/ErrorHandler.php on line 612

Может кто сталкивался, подскажите плз.
До этих манипуляций все было ровно)

Comment: проверь права на локальную папку с логами (и вообще есть ли она)

Comment: вот я дурень! докатился) реально права. сорян за шухер) Спасибо!